# CMB2 metabox create select with list of post from CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, metabox

I create a metabox for listing the posts from CPT in a select:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type', 'post_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()) {  
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //
        $varID = get_the_id();
        $varName = get_the_title();
        $pageArray[$varID]=$varName;
    endwhile;   
}
...
array(
    'name'    => 'mb_name',
    'id'      => $prefix . 'mb_id',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $pageArray
)
```

the metabox is working fine, but the problem is that WP options-reading (posts_per_page) is limiting the number of post. 
I can´t figure out how to do it to show all the post in my CPT without the limit of WP setting.

Comment: Did you try using this addon? https://github.com/CMB2/cmb2-attached-posts

Comment: not sure what limit you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Your WP_Query has 'post_per_page' instead of 'posts_per_page'.  (missing an "s" on posts)